# NoHandlerForCommandException: observed when command raised just after application starts

Tags: axon

When my spring aplication come up and makes an attempt to issue any command using send method `NoHandlerForCommandException` is observed. This exception is observed just after the startup of the application and after a few moments it can find the handler and everything works as expected.

How can I know if the command bus and all other command handling components are setup before initiating any command?

I have read somewhere on stackoverflow that in coming version of Axon Framework an event would be emitted after setting up or after receiving the start signal from command handling configuration, has that been introduced?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue you are talking about is [this one](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/issues/880) which is not done yet but you can follow it up there.

To your problem, the only way to do that right now is to wait a few seconds before you start your testing (not the best approach).
There are ways to check using Axon Server API if the command handlers are already registered there or not but that's not an easy task and not beautiful as well so I would stick with the `wait` approach by now until it gets properly fixed.